# How to change viewport of 2D image?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I'm developing a mobile app for money recognition. Now I'm trying to build the database for this app.

The next step is generate some image from an original image in different view. Here is the example:

***Original:***

[image]

***View 1:***

[image]

As you can see in above image, the view 1 image is view of original from left edge. What I want to do is generate 4 image from original with 4 view from left, right, bottom, up. With the very large number of image, I can not use camera to capture so I need a write a program to do this work. But I can not found any thing about this issue.

Please tell me are there any tools to do what I need? or any library, framework support this? I can code on MATLAB and openCV.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As written, this question is far too broad and library/tool/etc. recommendations are outside the scope of SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. you assume that your original image is looking with 90 degree angle on a planar object
2. you assume some camera intrinsic parameters (e.g. focal point in the middle of the image and uniform pixel size), some camera extrinsics (e.g. looking "down" with some position from above the plane) and some plane coordinates (xy-plane). This will result in every pixel to lie on some coordinates of the plane.
3. you change your camera extrinic parameters by rotating around the camera center
4. you project some (4 or more) plane positions to your camera image (e.g. use `cv::projectPoints()`).
5. you compute the perspective homography that describes the pixel "motion" between both camera views (input pixel positions are those projected plane positions and the same plane positions in your original image)
6. remember that homography for each chosen view.
7. for each image, just use those homographies, you don't have to recompute them because they are the same for each image.

EDIT:
this is how it looks like in action (sorry for ugly code):

```
cv::Mat getRotationMatrixAroundY(double angle)
{
    cv::Mat rVec;

    cv::Mat deg45 = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_64FC1);
    double cos45 = cos(CV_PI*angle/180.0);
    double sin45 = sin(CV_PI*angle/180.0);

    // different axis:
    /*      deg45.at<double>(1,1) = cos45;      deg45.at<double>(1,2) = sin45;      deg45.at<double>(0,0) = 1;      deg45.at<double>(2,1) = -sin45;     deg45.at<double>(2,2) = cos45;      */

    /*      deg45.at<double>(0,0) = cos45;      deg45.at<double>(0,1) = in45;       deg45.at<double>(2,2) = 1;      deg45.at<double>(1,0) = -sin45;     deg45.at<double>(1,1) = cos45;      */


    deg45.at<double>(0,0) = cos45;
    deg45.at<double>(0,2) = sin45;
    deg45.at<double>(1,1) = 1;
    deg45.at<double>(2,0) = -sin45;
    deg45.at<double>(2,2) = cos45;

    cv::Rodrigues(deg45, rVec);

    return rVec;
}

// banknode training sample generator
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/bankNode.jpg");

    std::vector<cv::Point3f> pointsOnPlane;

    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(0-input.cols/2,0-input.rows/2,0));
    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(input.cols-input.cols/2,0-input.rows/2,0));
    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(input.cols-input.cols/2,input.rows-input.rows/2,0));
    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(0-input.cols/2,input.rows-input.rows/2,0));





    std::vector<cv::Point2f> originalPointsInImage;
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,0));
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(input.cols,0));
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(input.cols,input.rows));
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,input.rows));

    std::cout << "original pixel positions:" << std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<originalPointsInImage.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << originalPointsInImage[i] << std::endl;

    cv::Mat cameraIntrinsics = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64FC1);

    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(0,0) = 500.0;
    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(1,1) = 500.0;
    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(0,2) = input.cols/2.0;
    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(1,2) = input.rows/2.0;

    std::vector<double> distCoefficients;

    cv::Mat rVec;
    cv::Mat tVec;
    cv::solvePnP(pointsOnPlane, originalPointsInImage, cameraIntrinsics, distCoefficients, rVec, tVec);


    // let's increase the distance a bit
    tVec = tVec*2;
    double angle = -45; // degrees


    cv::Mat rVec2 = getRotationMatrixAroundY(angle);

    // TODO: how to "add" some rotation to a previous rotation in Rodrigues?!?
    // atm just overwrite:


    std::vector<cv::Point2f> projectedPointsOnImage;
    cv::projectPoints(pointsOnPlane, rVec2, tVec, cameraIntrinsics, distCoefficients, projectedPointsOnImage);


    cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(originalPointsInImage, projectedPointsOnImage);

    cv::Mat warped;
    cv::warpPerspective(input, warped, H, input.size());




    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("warped", warped);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

with this result:

[image]

as you can see there is one problem: the rotation isn't around the center of the banknode. If someone can fix that, the result will be better. Atm I had to scale the translation part, this might not be necessary afterwards. Probably the problem occurs because of wrong translation + rotation combination.

for comparison: tranlation scaled by 1.5:

[image]

and not scaled:

[image]

Is this what you wanted to achieve (if the viewing center of the camera could be fixed at the middle of the banknode)?

Comment: I think homography is not what I need because image generated from original must have the right ratio. Homography make us have the feeling that view from left or right but the object is distorted.

Comment: since you compute the homography from a virtually moved/rotated camera (point 1-4 is important before computing the homography!) you won't get any better results without knowing the 3D model of your object. If I find the time I'll demonstrate it with some code...

Comment: if you however mean that you need the right intrinsics (and maybe extrinsic) parameters of your camera, then it'll be even easier (if you can provide those parameters).

Comment: pls tell me Which parameters you need?

Comment: camera intrinsics of the camera which was used to capture your input images

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will see your answer carefully and feedback if there are some problem.

Comment: How do you tranlation scaled by 1.5?

Comment: tVec = tVec*1.5; you can try to add some offset to  the translation vector too, like tVec.at<double>(1,0) -= offset;

Comment: Your code work perfectly. Can you help me to create the view from the right and bottom of above image?

Comment: view from right should be the same except that you have to choose a negative angle.

Comment: View from bottom/top will rotate around a different axis. see rotation matrices on wikipedia to find the right matrix/axis

Comment: Thanks for your support. I did it :)

Comment: How can I create a view from a corner of the banknote? Like rotate image 45 degrees from original and then view from left.

Comment: you can multiply two rotation matrices to rotate around 2 different axes

Comment: yep, you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html) for a Projective Transformation using Matlab. You only have to find the right warping matrices (so-called [homographies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision))). You can build them with the mathematics on wikipedia, given a rotation matrix and an assumed camera intrinsics.

However, I think synthetically created training data possibly causes some problems regarding your task. The reflecting parts of bank notes are engineered to look different from different view points. You'll lose information.

Further, do not underestimate the effort, which will be necessary to develop this. There is quite sophisticated research going on in this field.

See here:

[Towards Mobile Recognition and Verification of Holograms using Orthogonal Sampling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=720moVaLQdA)

[Mobile User Interfaces for Efficient Verification of Holograms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXKjRU78zKA)

Comment: I can not use homopgraphy for this image because the object inside will be distorted. pls give me another way